# cannot display reviews in jquery window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I just want to display the reviews on the dialog box but it doesn't work. Please help me. I am trying to do this for a week.

Here is the data which should be displayed:

```
{"results":[{"review_text":"good"},{"review_text":"not bad"},{"review_text":"great"}]}
```

here is my view code:

```
<div id="see_all_reviews">  
  <div id="load_reviews"></div>
  </div>  
<?php
$data = array(
    'name' => $places_id,
    'class' => 'all_reviews',    
    'content' => 'Reviews'    
    );
   echo form_button($data);
?>
```

here is my js file:

```
$(".all_reviews").click(function() {
    var self = this;
    var places_id_all_reviews = $(self).attr("name");
    $.post('filter/get_reviews', { id: id }, function(data) {
        var reviews_text = data.results[0].review_text;
        $("#load_reviews").text(reviews_text);
    });
}, "json").error(function() {
    $("#load_reviews").text(data.message);
});

$("#see_all_reviews").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Reviews",
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    width: 600,
    height: 600,
    close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: what is the result so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this **updated**

```
var places_id_all_reviews = $(self).attr("name");
    $.post('filter/get_reviews', {
        id: id
    }, function(data) {

        $.each(data.results, function(i, res) {

            // Let's create the DOM
            var item = $('<div>'),
                title = $('<h1>'),
                info = $('<p>');


            info.text(res.review_text);

            // Append the infos to the item
            item.append(title, info);

            // Append the item to the container
            item.appendTo($("#load_reviews"));
        });

        $("#see_all_reviews").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: "Reviews",
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            width: 600,
            height: 600,
            close: function() {
                $(this).dialog('destroy');
            }
        });
    });
    });
    }, "json").error(function() {
        $("#load_reviews").text(data.message);
    });
```

**Updated**

try empty the html of the reviews contain as following change in this part of code as

```
close: function() {
                     $("#load_reviews").html("");
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                }
```

Comment: great! It works. The only problem is that it displays the first review only. I would like to display the first five reviews. Could you help me to write a loop which will do that? Then I will add a button "Show more" which will load the next five reviews as well.

Comment: now it displays all the reviews but when I click on the 'Reviews' button second time, it appends all the reviews once more so I have duplicate values.I guess I should delete those values on closing but don't know how...

Comment: I tried **$("#load_reviews").html("");** and even **$("#load_reviews").val("");** but it doesn't delete the data. It's strange.

Comment: try `$("#load_reviews").empty();`? Or maybe the close function isn't being called? Put a `console.log("clicked");` in there to see if its actually going inside the close function.

Comment: yes, it is going inside the close function. I just replaced $(this).dialog('destroy'); with $(self).dialog('destroy'); and it deletes the values on closing but it also deletes the rest of data which should not be deleted and the logic did not work.